# Dataflow UDF to extract specific data from kafka json message

Tags: json, apache-kafka, google-cloud-dataflow

I am receiving test data via kafka in json format.
The issue I have is dataflow is trying to treat all parts of the message as fields whereas I only need the "data" part of the message. Fields and values..

This is the message format (NOTE: I cannot change this format, it is auto generated from source)...

```
{
    "magic": "atMSG",
    "type": "DT",
    "headers": null,
    "messageSchemaId": null,
    "messageSchema": null,
    "message": {
        "data": {
            "id": 196,
            "column_1_varchar": "jEwNWQ0NTFlNDRhMmE5ODYxOTMxMmRi",
            "column_2_varchar": "zU0OTg0NDViNDg2Z",
            "column_3_varchar": "2U4M2ZkNDZjY2YzMGM3ODNmOGNiZmQw",
            "column_4_varchar": "TJjYTVhZGExOGUxMTQ3M",
            "column_5_varchar": "DdhYWRiY2U0NWQwYTMyN2FhMzRiNmY4NjEzZTU",
            "column_6_varchar": "DE1OTk5MTc3NzFiNzJhNzhk",
            "column_7_varchar": "jkwYzI2MDR",
            "column_8_varchar": "TM2M2Q2ZDRjOTczN",
            "column_9_varchar": "2JkNjg1MmYzMDY5N",
            "column_10_varchar": "DU4MmQwMjNiZjdkNjhjNDcwZTVjMTNlMzIxMDl",
            "column_11_varchar": "DU4NGFlMmE2NDk4ZTYxY",
            "column_12_varchar": "DU5MTEzMTViMjExOTdiMjQ",
            "column_13_INT": 53,
            "column_14_INT": 448,
            "column_15_INT": 6562,
            "column_16_INT": 93704,
            "column_17_INT": 716496,
            "column_18_INT": 7713572,
            "column_19_INT": 70729683,
            "UPDT_DTTM": "2023-02-13 10:52:16"
        },
        "beforeData": null,
        "headers": {
            "operation": "REFRESH",
            "changeSequence": "",
            "timestamp": "",
            "streamPosition": "",
            "transactionId": "",
            "changeMask": null,
            "columnMask": null,
            "transactionEventCounter": null,
            "transactionLastEvent": null
        }
    }
}
```

So from "data" I need fields id and value, column_1_varchar and value e.t.c.

How can I put this into a UDF file to extract only what I need ?

Comment: You are using an usual Dataflow job or a template ?

Comment: Have you tried to use any map function to parse the JSON? What deserializer are you using from Kafka consumer (data in Kafka is only bytes, so how are you getting the JSON object, and can you change that code to return the data you actually want)?

Comment: I am using the Kafka to BiqQuery template on GCP.
The kafka messages are being generated by Qlik Replicate.